# Opportunity team members: list view buttons not available to specific users with same role and profile as others

Tags: list-button, opportunity-teams

I have several users in a team with the same profile, role (high up in the hierarchy), and permission sets.

However, two specific users are unable to view the Opportunity Team related list buttons on the opportunity record to add team members. They previously were able to and now they no longer can. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed.

We compared a test sandbox where they have the exact same role and profiles as in production, but they are able to view the buttons in the Sandbox.

We already checked permissions, page layouts, and lighting pages but nothing sticks out. Is there something else I should check?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Record-level access and different data (records) in sandbox vs prod is another set of things to look at.

Comment: Does this help? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336113&type=1)